# Java function with Map.Class parameter in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use a Jackson's ObjectMapper() function: `convertValue`.

It takes 2 parameters (3 overloads):

1. (Object, Call)
2. (Object, TypeReference)
3. (Object, JavaType)

I have the following code:

```
val m = new ObjectMapper()
val map: Map[String, Object] = m.convertValue(bean, classOf[Map])
```

which doesn't work with error `Type Mismatch. Expected JavaType actual Class[Map]`.

I tested with `classOf[java.util.Map]`, `Map.getClass`, etc. but can't make it work.

How should I send that parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: look at https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType.html. See

> Instances can (only) be constructed by `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory`.

Step 2: look at https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html.

Then you can see it can be used as e.g.

```
m.getTypeFactory.constructMapType(classOf[java.util.Map[_, _]], classOf[YourKey], classOf[YourValue])
```

Comment: This throws me: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mapper to get the JavaType, for example:

```
val stringType:JavaType  = mapper.constructType(String.class);
```

You can try the following for your problem:

```
val m = new ObjectMapper()
val mapType:JavaType = mapper.constructType(java.util.Map.class)
val map: Map[String, Object] = m.convertValue(bean, mapType)
```